# How to avoid memory leaks with View

Tags: enthought, traitsui

With the following program:

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Int, Instance
from traitsui.api import View

class NewView(View):
    def __del__(self):
        print('deleting NewView')

class A(HasTraits):
    new_view = Instance(NewView)
    def __del__(self):
        print('deleting {}'.format(self))

    a = Int

    def default_traits_view(self):
        new_view = NewView('a')
        return new_view
```

running

```
a = A()
del(a)
```

returns

```
 deleting <__main__.A object at 0x12a016a70>
```

as it should.

If I do

```
a = A()
a.configure_traits()
```

and after closing the dialog:

```
del(a)
```

I have the same kind of message:

```
deleting <__main__.A object at 0x12a016650>
```

with no mention of the NewView being deleted.

In geneal, what are the good practices to avoid memory leaks with Traits and TraitsUI?

Comment: Good question, Yves, with the leak seemingly confirmed by some quick experimentation with a `weakref` to your `new_view`. My first (very tentative) guess is that because Views are lightweight and not expected to proliferate, this has not been considered a significant problem. My second guess is that there is hidden magic. :) I've asked some TraitsUI wizards for an explanation.  If we don't get an answer, then I would suggest posting as a TraitsUI issue where it will retain visibility over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's going on here is that the `NewView` object is involved in a reference cycle, and the objects in that cycle don't get automatically collected as part of CPython's primary reference-counting-based object deallocation mechanism. However, they should be eventually collected as part of CPython's cyclic garbage collector, or you can force that collection by doing a `gc.collect()`, so there should be no actual long-term memory leak here.

Ironically, attempting to detect that eventual collection by adding a `__del__` method to `NewView` hinders the process, since it renders the `NewView` object uncollectable: at least in Python 2, Python won't try to collect cycles containing objects that have `__del__` methods. See the [`gc` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) for details. (Python 3 is somewhat cleverer here, thanks to the changes outlined in [PEP 442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).) So with the `__del__` method, using Python 2, there will indeed be a slow memory leak over time. The solution is to remove the `__del__` method.

Here's a graph showing the reference cycle (actually, this shows the whole strongly-connected component of the object graph containing the `NewView` object): nodes are the objects involved, and arrows go from referrers to referents. In the bottom right portion of the graph, you see that the `NewView` object has a reference to its top-level `Group` (via the `content` attribute), and that `Group` object has a reference back to the original view (the `container` attribute). There are similar cycles going on elsewhere in the view.

[image: NewView reference cycle]

It's probably worth opening a feature request on the Traits UI tracker: in theory, it should be possible to break the reference cycles manually when the view is no longer needed, though in practice that might require significant reworking of the Traits UI source.

Here's some code that demonstrates that (with the `__del__` methods removed) a call to `gc.collect` does collect the `NewView` object: it stores a weak reference to the view on the `A` instance, with a callback that reports when that view is garbage collected.

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Int, Instance
from traitsui.api import View

import gc
import weakref

class NewView(View):
    pass


def report_collection(ref):
    print("NewView object has been collected")


class A(HasTraits):
    a = Int

    def default_traits_view(self):
        new_view = NewView('a')
        self.view_ref = weakref.ref(new_view, report_collection)
        return new_view


def open_view():
    a = A()
    a.configure_traits()
    print("Collecting cyclic garbage")
    gc.collect()
    print("Cyclic garbage collection complete")
```

On my machine, here's what I see when `open_view` is called:

```
>>> open_view()
Collecting cyclic garbage
NewView object has been collected
Cyclic garbage collection complete
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I just had to add `kind = 'modal'` to the `new_view`definition on my Mac for your code to get the result.
I was using these transient views with Chaco plots and huge (15Mpix) images, and I was exploding the memory